# What is Sharding in the FSDP, and how is FSDP different from Pipeline Parallel?

Tags: algorithm, pytorch, gpu, huggingface-transformers, multi-gpu

Huggingface explains FSDP as:

> sharding the model parameters, gradients, and optimizer states across data parallel processes and it can also offload sharded model parameters to a CPU.

And Pipeline parallelism as :

> split up vertically (layer-level) across multiple GPUs, so that only one or several layers of the model are places on a single gpu. Each gpu processes in parallel different stages of the pipeline...

How are these different? If I have a simple 2-layer model, what does FSDP do that pipeline parallel does not? I've read descriptions that say something like "in PP the model is split across GPU while in FSDP the model is *sharded*. Doesn't shared just mean split in parts? TIA!

Answer (score 2):

In FSDP each GPU gets part of each layer, in pipeline parallelism each GPU gets its own layers.

Say you have 2 gpus.

For FSDP, layer one will get sharded, and layer two will get sharded. Each GPU will have their own independent batch. For the first step, neither gpu can compute layer one, since they each only have half of that layer. So they will send their portions of layer one to each other and then compute their outputs of layer one. Note that we are saving memory since layer 2 is still split up. Then, they will reshard layer 1 to free memory, and send layer two to each other. The main idea behind FSDP is that a gpu only has the entirety of a layer when it's using that layer. Otherwise that layer is sharded.

In pipeline parallelism on the other hand, instead of splitting each layer and communicating them as necessary，one GPU will always have layer one, and the other GPU will always have layer two. The first GPU will send it's output of layer 1 to the second GPU.